# I have 2 sets of data mapped to each other. Is there a way to based on the value of another variable check that corresponding variable for its value?

Tags: c++, variables

So I have 64 variables called S0O through S63O. These are corresponding to the chess squares on a board. Now I have a function that walks through and marks each of these variables as TRUE(Occupied) or FALSE(Empty). Now i'm trying to take a variable(BP1 aka Black Pawn 1) which has a value 0 through 63 and I want to check if the square in front of it is empty so (BP1 - 8). I was recommended to try a unordered map which I tried but I could not find a way to take a variable value being a number and run ti though the Keys to find the output I am looking for. I am open to any ideas.

Comment: If your elements have unique indexes that start at 0 and are bound to a relatively small number (in this case less than 64) you can simply use an `std::vector` or `std::array` to represent your board squares.

Comment: I thought about doing that but that wasn't really the part I was asking about. I did many different variables to track them more easily and for multi number entries they take up multiple spaces inside of the Array which would be frustrating when they are changing.(Based on my understanding, I could be wrong if so please correct me)

Comment: If I understand correctly, you have 64 individually named variables which represents the state of your board. If this is the case, you will have a very difficult time generalizing. You will first have to replace these individual variables with a single array before you can do anything interesting with them.

Comment: I took another look at what you said and thought about it and you're right this work work perfectly. This also helps with the next problem I was having so thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As François Andrieux pointed out if I use an array to put all these in a grid I can move about and edit specific "squares" inside of the board. So if my input is stored in variable `BP1P = 48;` Then I can take this value and check for it occupied with something like ([BP1P-8] == 'O').